# what is the difference of type record and type row in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

As title shown, when reading the manul, I found type record type and row type, which are both composite type. However, I want to figure out their difference.

Answer (score 1):

They're similar once defined but tend to have different use cases.

A RECORD type has no predefined structure and is typically used when the row type might change or is out of your control, for example if you're referencing a record in a FOR LOOP.

ROWTYPE is predefined of a particular table row structure and thus if anything deviates from that structure you will get runtime errors.

It all depends what you're trying to achieve.

For cursor loops I use a RECORD>

For more information:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-declarations.html